# Image gallery plugin

Tags: plugins, images, gallery

Can you recommend a tutorial or a plugin in wordpress that lets you achieve a similar gallery, like this http://www.whitehouse.gov/photos-and-video/photogallery/may-2011-photo-day

Large Preview then at the bottom a thumbnails then an album.

I also like cooliris because it supports fetching images from facebook and flikr. Another feature I like about it is its sharing options, you can easily share those images in facebook. The only thing I don't like is its interface, its not fully customizable, the arrows left and right are hardly to be seen, the animation is too techno for my project.

I need a gallery where thumbnails where thumbnails can easily be browse, and it also has an album so its organize. It would be a plus if you have an option to pull images from flikr or facebook and you can share them via facebook or twitter.

Let me know if you know a software that is close to my description.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to create custom templates, but your reference page is fully achievable using the [NextGen Gallery](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery) plugin.

Comment: Maybe its just me, I haven't tried NextGen Gallery yet but isn't too slow? do you any other site who use it? I find the demo kinda heavy.

Comment: Never rely on demos they are usually going to be slow. Some popular wordpress sites use it like intomobile.com i believe still uses it.

Comment: @xLRDxREVENGEx thanks for the review... I guess I'll try it. Thanks. i cant find nexGen Gallery in intomobile.com.

Comment: Well they use to use it. Most of moved on. In all honesty it all depends on your server and its processors, ram, etc. You can have a decent server and not run scripts the well but upgrade to another ram size and have a faster running site. If your on a shared server then that depends on server stats and how many people are you sharing with and lets face it some hosts at least in my past experience have 100's even 1000's on one. If you notice a speed drop and are on a shared server consider rackspace cloud server with there basic and you have full root and they manage and it starts at $12 rough

Comment: yeah good point... what cloud hosting are your recommending? i haven't seen any cloud hosting nearing $12-$15, i usually seen $30-$50 per month

Comment: I use NextGen here: http://www.chipbennett.net/photos/ (though as Chris mentions below, it's overkill for my use case, and I'm working on converting the galleries to native WordPress media galleries).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the exact same jQuery plugin the White House is using, [Galleria.](http://galleria.aino.se/).  It's very well documented with lots of [tutorials and instructions.](http://galleria.aino.se/docs/1.2/getting_started/beginners_guide/)

I think NextGen Gallery is overkill and the all options are confusing and the extra tables added to the db aren't really needed.

Comment: In general I agree (and am in the process of converting all of my NextGen galleries to native WordPress galleries). But the OP asked for existing Plugins that could accomplish a particular page output. :)